# NewRelic - monitoring process

Tags: monitoring, newrelic

Any idea if we can monitor a particular process in NewRelic  whether it's running or not running?

I see that once we get to the detail of the server, we can see each process's status but my exact requirement is to get notification if the process in the server is running or not.

Answer (score 1):

Use [Newrelic Infrastructure](https://newrelic.com/products/infrastructure/features) option

After you add it to your server:

- enter Infrastructure menu
- Goto settings -> Alerts and add alert:
- select process running alert type and the process you want to monitor
- choose Trigger an alert when no processes are running
- add policy with your email to get notify